# Hidden parts of UI (hidden in code) still show up in simulator

Tags: ios

I am using Xcode 8. In my code, I have certain items hidden, but when I launch the simulator to test, those same items show up. Is there something that I am missing?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var logoImg: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var howManyTapsTxt: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var playBtn: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var tapBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var tapsLbl: UILabel!

    @IBAction func onPlayBtnPressed (sender: UIButton!) {
        logoImg.isHidden = true
        playBtn.isHidden = true
        howManyTapsTxt.isHidden = true

        tapBtn.isHidden = false
        tapsLbl.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

My code is above. The logo, howManyTapsTxt, and playBtn should be the only items shown when the simulator is launched. And when the playBtn is pressed, the tapsLbl and tapBtn should be the only items shown. But that is not the case. Any help/guidance is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Where/how are you making some of the views initially hidden? None of your posted code makes any views hidden when the view controller is first displayed.

Comment: that is the thing, when the simulator is first launched everything is displayed. I want it to be where when the simulator is launched the tapsBtn and tapsLbl is hidden.

Comment: And that's my point. You've taken no steps to make anything hidden initially. Is that your question? How to make some views hidden initially?

Comment: Yes, that is my question. Sorry for the confusion or if I wasn't making any sense before. I am new to learning this skill. I had previously changed the Alpha to 0 (instead of 1), but that seemed to only hide it in the mainstoryboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your posted code makes no attempt to set the initial state of any of your views. The typical solution is to set the state in the `viewDidLoad` method.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Set the initial state of your views here
    tapBtn.isHidden = true
    tapsLbl.isHidden = true
}
```

The other option is to mark these views as hidden in Interface Builder.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I appreciate it and I did more research on the viewDidLoad method and I understand!